# Markov Inequality and MGF's

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

I am reading up on how to apply the Markov and Chebyshev inequalities and the first equation of the text says for any $u>0$ we have

$$
P(X\ge E(X)+t)=P(e^{uX}\ge e^{u(E(X)+t)})\le e^{-u(E(X)+t)}E(e^{uX})
$$

The inequality part makes sense to me as it is simply a direct application of Markov's inequality, but the equality preceding it seems weird. Would it be true that

$$
P(X\ge E(X)+t)=P(f(X)\ge f(E(X)+t))
$$

where $f$ is any monotonically increasing function?

Comment: The function $f$ needs to be strictly increasing, else you can take $f(x)=0$ as a counter-example.

Comment: If $f$ is strictly increasing then $x<y$ if and only if $f(x)<f(y)$.  Similarly, $x \leq y$ if and only if $f(x) \leq f(y)$.

Comment: To sum up, for every positive $u$, the events $\{X\ge E(X)+t\}$ and $\{e^{uX}\ge e^{u(E(X)+t)}\}$ coincide.

Comment: Is there a resource I could look at with these sort of analytic results wrt probability theory? I have studied all of Royden's Real Analysis, but nothing specifically related to probability.